# Get attribute of random jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get a data-attribute of an image on my page using the following code, but it doesn't work

```
var rand_el = $('img').get(Math.floor(Math.random() * $('img').length)).attr('data-id');
```

But I just get the following console log:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object `#<HTMLImageElement>` has no method 'attr'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) returns a DOM element reference. Use [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index while still returning a jQuery object.

```
var rand_el = $('img').eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * $('img').length)).attr('data-id');
```

Comment: yeah I really should have picked up that it was returning the HTML element rather than the jQ object. thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

The [`get` method](http://api.jquery.com/get/) returns the wrapped DOM element(s), not a jQuery object. The [eq method](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) returns a jQuery object however.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you have a javascript object and not a jQ object. this should work for you.

```
$($('img').get(Math.floor(Math.random() * $('img').length))).attr('data-id');
```